# My UL element doesn't place list items verticaly even when I use flex column on it

Tags: html, css

I have got a container element with 3 items inside it: profile image, short description and list element. Here is the CSS code of this container element:

```
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 2fr;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

The list items inside the UL element arent stacking vertically, they are standing one to each other. Why is that happening? I haven't applied any special CSS to the UL element or list items. I checked in Chrome Developer Tools to see what display etc. this UL has, so here it is:

- user agent stylesheet (display: block and other primary features of ul)
- only text properties like font-size, color, line-height

And lastly here is my HTML code of this container:

```
<div class="container">
          <img class="round-img" src="url" alt="">
          <div>
            <h2>John Doe</h2>
            <p>Developer at Microsoft</p>
            <p>Seattle, WA</p>
            <a href="profile.html"">View profile</a>
          </div>

          <ul>
            <li class="text-primary">
              <i class="fas fa-check"></i> HTML
              <i class="fas fa-check"></i> CSS
              <i class="fas fa-check"></i> JavaScript
              <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Python
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Even when I add display: flex and flex-direction: column to this UL, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet work's fine for me.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <img class="round-img" src="url" alt="">
   <div>
      <h2>John Doe</h2>
      <p>Developer at Microsoft</p>
      <p>Seattle, WA</p>
      <a href="profile.html"">View profile</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="text-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i> HTML
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i> CSS
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i> JavaScript
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Python
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show them in row they just remove `<ul>` tag and wrap them around `<div class="myClass">`
where `myClass` will have following properties:

```
.myClass{
   display : flex;
   flex-direction : column;
}
```

```css
.myClass{
   display : flex;
   flex-direction : column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <img class="round-img" src="url" alt="">
          <div>
            <h2>John Doe</h2>
            <p>Developer at Microsoft</p>
            <p>Seattle, WA</p>
            <a href="profile.html"">View profile</a>
          </div>
          <br>

          <div  class= "myClass">
              <i class="fas fa-check"><input type="checkbox"> HTML</i>
              <i class="fas fa-check"><input type="checkbox"> CSS</i>
              <i class="fas fa-check"><input type="checkbox"> JavaScript</i>
              <i class="fas fa-check"><input type="checkbox"> Python</i>
          </div>
</div>
```